# How to dynamically allocate an array of pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, arrays

I do not know the number of horse. I have already tried to do it, but I am getting errors and I don't know why. I am basically trying to create an array of pointers to objects. The class everything is in is called horse. Here is what I have. I am still getting errors from the c++ compiler.

```
horse::horse(string horse_Name, string rider_Name, int distance_Traveled, int max_Distance_Per_Second)
{

    distance_Traveled = 0;
    const int number_Of_Horses = 1;

    horse **ptr = new horse*[number_Of_Horses];

    *ptr[number_Of_Horses] =
    {
    horse(horse_Name, rider_Name, distance_Traveled, max_Distance_Per_Second)
    };


    max_Running_Distance_Per_Second(max_Distance_Per_Second);

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting and on what lines?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are trying to accomplish and where you see the error(s). See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
distance_Traveled = 0;
```

Since distance_Traveled is not passed by reference, it will not change the original value. This may be one error.

```
horse **ptr = new horse*[number_Of_Horses];
```

This pointer is declared correctly; however, when you try to use iteration(or other expression, just my conjecture), you have to be careful,BECAUSE:

When it is a array, *ptr[number_Of_Horses] is illegal because an array start with 0, not 1. This is a common error. This may be a major issue.